Same Question, but in English
I'll be honest: my Italian is limited to what I've picked up as a musician. That is to say, it's not great.
I was typesetting some old music, and I ran into something that I thought was confusing. After doing some Googling, I found this question. From what I can gather with Google Translate, it's exactly what I want to know, but as my Italian isn't really reliable, I'm not 100% certain of what everything means.
Should I ask a new question and try ask the same thing, but in English, or should I just ask for a translation of the question and answer posts? Or perhaps there's a better alternative altogether?

Welcome to Italian.SE! I'll try to answer to your question later.

I don't know about how to tackle in general such a situation, but as the author of that answer, I'll be glad to add to it an English translation (on Monday).

And I can try to translate my question as soon as I have some time (but improvements of my English translation will be welcomed).

Now the question is translated into English, but, as I've said, improvements are welcomed.

And I translated my answer.

Wow, thanks, everyone! that helps a lot!

In my opinion, the same question written in English would be a duplicate and, as every duplicate, should be closed and receive no answers. That is, asking a new question in English doesn't seem a good idea to me.
I think the best solution would be to translate  the existing question and its anwser into English and I hope some of the users of this site can do it.

Can I try my best to understand the original post, then ask for clarifications on how it applies to my particular situation?

@Calculuswhiz If there is something you don't understand in an answer written in Italian, you can ask a question about what you don't understand.

I think a good compromise solution would be to custom-flag the question asking moderators to translate the question and answer. This might take some time, but we will eventually do it.
If you do not want to rely on moderators, you can also try to ask on the Bar Sport if some user would be willing to do the job.

Yes, asking on chat is probably better. Flagging for moderation attention should be done when effectively there is something only moderators can do; it should not be done if, for example, the only action a moderator could eventually take is down-voting the post.

@kiamlaluno In principle yes, I agree. Unfortunately the chat is not much active (if you ping me there I should see the message though), so I was trying to suggest a workaround with the custom flags, even if it is a (very minor) abuse of the system.
